# Rigorous proof that $x \in a \cup b \iff x \in a \lor x \in b$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

The axiom of union states $\forall x \exists y \forall z [z \in y \iff \exists w(z \in w \wedge w \in x )]$. Therefore, letting $a,b$ be sets and denoting $\bigcup \{a,b\}$ as $a \cup b$  one has that $x \in a \cup b \iff \exists w[w \in \{a,b\} \wedge x \in w]$. Is it valid to manipulate these symbols as follows:

\begin{align}
x \in a \cup b &\iff \exists w(x \in w \wedge w \in \{a,b\})
\\&\iff \exists w(x \in w \wedge (w = a \lor w = b))
\\&\iff \exists w((x \in w \wedge w = a) \lor (x \in w \wedge w = b))
\\&\iff x \in a \lor x \in b.
\end{align}

I am worried about the existential quantifier and how to get rid of it properly without making anything up. Any comment/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to prove: $\exists w~(x\in w\land w=a) {\implies} x\in a~,$ and $x\in a {\implies} \exists w~(x\in w\land w=a) $ .

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is some missing step between hypothesis and conclusion and that I can't really do as I did?

Comment: No.  I am saying that there is no issue .

Comment: You could be more formal and show a few more steps between the 3rd and 4th (final) lines of your proof. You may need to learn the inference rules for existential elimination. You could also use either the definition of equality or axiom of extensionality if you want a more detailed/verbose proof.